# How do I 'zoom' a graph so all the nodes are in the browser window?

Tags: neo4j

The graph loads in my browser but I have to scroll all around to see the nodes. How do I zoom in and out?

Answer (score 3):

It is explained in https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-zoom-in-out-within-the-graph-visualization-of-the-browser/

So :

1. Make browser window become **full screen**
2. Use magnifying glass icon

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: That helps but I need a way to zoom such that everything is displayed, without having to zoom in and out until I get there.